# React: useState hooks inside nested arrow functions

Tags: reactjs, use-state, react-functional-component

I've been trying to understand what is the correct way to update the state of a functional component from inside a nested arrow function. Inside, these functions the state is stale as far as I understand so this:

```
function F() {
 const [x, setX] = useState(0);
 const nestedSetX = () => {
  setX(x + 1);
 }
 return <button onClick={nestedSetX}>{x}</button>
}
```

I see that using refs works:

```
function F() {
 const [x, setX] = useState(0);
 const xRef = useRef(0);
 const nestedSetX = () => {
  xRef.current = xRef.current + 1;
  setX(xRef);
 }
 return <button onClick={nestedSetX}>{x}</button>
}
```

But it seems like an awfully awkward way of doing it.
What is the correct way of doing it?

**EDIT(solution):**

```
function F() {
 const [x, setX] = useState(0);
 const nestedSetX = () => {
  setX(x => x + 1);
 }
 return <button onClick={nestedSetX}>{x}</button>
}
```

Comment: this should work setX(x => x + 1); this way you can get the current state value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you like to try this?

```
function F() {
 const [x, setX] = useState(0);
 const nestedSetX = () => {
  setX((prevState) => prevState + 1);
 }
 return <button onClick={() => nestedSetX() }>{x}</button>
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. Can you please add some details why this works?